# Did people write on loose leaf or directly in notebook in middle age?

Tags: middle-ages, writing

Did Isaac Newton handwrite directly in notebooks or on loose leafs and then make notebooks from this papers?

In other words, could a blank notebook be bought or did people first have to write on loose leaf and then sew papers into notebooks?

In case of a book, one must first write or press letters on pages and then sew the papers into a book.

I found that [notebooks was invented long before Newton](https://globalasiaprintings.com/blog/history-of-notebooks/), but I can't find what was the order of writing.

Comment: There are many examples of table books and notebooks at that time. Even some [studies](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/29468359_Notebooks_as_memory_aids_Precepts_and_practices_in_early_modern_England). What preliminary research did you do? What did it show?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786). Newton didn't write in [tag:middle-ages]; a simple [google search](https://www.apmanuscripts.com/leonardo-da-vinci-collection/sir-isaac-newton-notebooks-1643-1727) will reveal your answer

Comment: [Richard Yeo: Notebooks, English Virtuosi, and Early Modern Science,  University of Chicago Press 2014](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.7208/9780226106731/html)

Comment: "to make a notebook from loose papers" would be extremely unusual. Since the invention of the book format in the first century, sheets are grouped, at least folded once, and then stitched together in the fold. The only way to make loose sheets hold together without folding is with a bulky [bandstick](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Adjustable_bandstick.jpg) – Glue that would hold them together was only invented in the 19th century. The order is almost assuredly binding first, writing later.

Comment: @ccprog So that is different procedure form making books? In middle edge people how copy books, first wrote text on sheets of paper after that binding into book..https://pinzelladesdetortosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/scriptorium.jpg

Comment: My understanding is that medieval codices were written [one quire at a time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex#Preparation_of_pages_for_writing) and folded afterwards. But a planned book layout where you mark out with lines where and in which order to write is different from filling in a notebook, one paragraph at a time if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Newton did both; in the middle ages, *nobody* did either.  Which question do you want answered?

[APManuscripts](https://www.apmanuscripts.com/leonardo-da-vinci-collection/sir-isaac-newton-notebooks-1643-1727) states

> This set of papers documents some of Newton's early mathematical thinking, work that would eventually develop into his theories of calculus. The texts include extracts he made from books he was reading, plus various notes and calculations - often on small scraps of paper that he had on hand.

I believe that "often on small scraps of paper that he had on hand. " answers your question.

On the other hand, [archaelogywiki](https://www.archaeology.wiki/blog/2012/07/20/newton%E2%80%99s-manuscripts-were-written-in-greek/) refers to a notebook that Newton purchased.  So the answer may depend on *what* Newton was writing and when.

The source you cite [GlobalAsianPrinting](https://globalasiaprintings.com/blog/history-of-notebooks/) does not reference notebooks;

> One of the most notable developments during this time was the widespread adoption of manuscripts as the primary medium for note-taking. Monks and scholars meticulously transcribed and reproduced texts by hand, resulting in a rich tradition of handwritten notes and annotations.

The manuscript culture of the Middle Ages also influenced the organization and structure of note-taking. Due to the scarcity and cost of materials, scholars often wrote in smaller formats, leading to the development of compact texts such as marginalia and annotations. These concise notes allowed for easy referencing and cross-referencing, enabling scholars to quickly locate specific information within a larger work. Moreover, the process of writing by hand encouraged active engagement with the material, promoting a deeper understanding and retention of knowledge. The Middle Ages thus set the stage for future advancements in note-taking techniques and laid the foundation for the scholarly practices that would evolve in the centuries to come.

This references taking notes _within [manuscripts_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuscript); it specifically mentions "marginalia and annotations" written in another book. This is not a notebook, [marginalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginalia) are

> Marginalia (or apostils) are marks made in the margins of a book or other document. They may be scribbles, comments, glosses (annotations), critiques, doodles, drolleries, or illuminations. *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginalia)*

---

Having said that, the [middle-ages](/questions/tagged/middle-ages) ended with the 15th century.  Newton didn't write on paper in the middle ages, because [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton) was born in 1642, the 17th century, long after the middle ages.

[AFandPA](https://www.afandpa.org/history-paper) points out:

> England began making large supplies of paper in the late 15th century . . .  .

(after most definitions of the middle ages)

Caveat!

- Newton wrote in England; *paper* was not readily available in England.  I'm aware that it was available in other countries and I'm aware that parchment could be collected, but (at least to my read), OP is asking a question with three specific criteria

1. Newton
2. Paper
3. Middle Ages

The intersection of those three is a null set.  Recognizing that Newton wrote in England, the intersection of any two of these is almost certainly a null set. (it is barely possible that Newton acquired rare & expensive paper, but I would want to see documentation of that assertion.)

Comment: here write that notebook was invented long before Newton. https://globalasiaprintings.com/blog/history-of-notebooks/

Comment: In all fairness, it should be noted that paper-making came to England comparably late. In Arab Iberia it was established in the 12th century, in Italy in the 13th/14th century. Merchant notebooks are known in Italy from the 14th century, for example the [Zibaldone da Canal](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/495446). [A student paper](https://www.academia.edu/1281770/A_Living_Text_Literacy_Identity_and_Fourteenth-Century_Merchants_in_the_Zibaldone_da_Canal) notes it contains both medieval and more modern instructional materials, making it "a bridge between these two eras".

Comment: I dislike the rather strong assertion that "in the middle ages, **nobody** did either" (emphasis repeated). -- "There is evidence that multiple parchment offcuts were sometimes bound together, by pricking a hole in them and pulling a cord through. These bundles, which essentially form a true notepad in the modern sense of the word, could be of considerable size. A specimen in the University Library, Würzburg consists of thirty slips." -- [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/humanities/medieval-world/medieval-book/using-medieval-book/a/medieval-notepads)